# Covert Conversation - A North Daniels' Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, cipher, story, geography

It's very important to keep your login details secure, which might entail not writing it down, encrypting them, or using a password manager. What you should not do is save them on some random USB and chuck it in your bag, because if you are, for example, a gang ringleader, someone might accidently dip their hand into your bag and fish it out.

Obviously, this is exactly the sort of thing D.S.I North Daniels loves doing - being sneaky. After tracking Simon Ukle for a few hours, he'd finally snagged a USB from his bag whilst distracting him with a pain au chocolat. After some digging, North found Simon's logins file, which contained his Wheresapp password. Brilliant...

However, after logging in, North was not greeted with oodles of juicy evidence, or any contact information - just one conversation with someone called Jude:

Simon: *Are you there Jude?*
Jude: *Xon j af. Vhomo amo vo foopjgt?*
Simon: *Uagg gaol tplo lyx ikrcnl yka dc ba!*
Jude: *Qawgf gas jycfg?*
Simon: *Vs ldwyst aisoo dwop vssc - awlpqnrjf ykqn lrsaso vwo swoy lswoy*
Jude: *Qcwfb fca bapirl?*
Simon: *Kspqsmnic np ijq wffjvst ji nq'p jvi - jify ni psqp. Hfwab wit vonqs qnsp*
Jude: *O mytrhfjpyt*
Simon: *We geep ip i opipan page - yjq otiff hjp ue fipe. Wiaopnjipo melqamed*
Jude: *Dbiad*
Simon: *Lm, ft's Sfkml!*

It seemed like the conversation was corrupted in some way, or maybe it was encoded. Simon took after his sister [Jane](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100345/place-of-safety-a-north-daniels-puzzle) - he always took things one step further

North whipped open his laptop, and after some speed-coding, the conversation was revealed...

*Yes...no?*

Well, it looked like gibberish, but North never had the knack for cryptic crosswords. It seems as though Grandma Daniels' skills may be useful after all...

---

What's the **FULLY** decoded conversation?

---

*Hints*

> 1. Simon says look at the four responses

> 2. Simon says watch out for any purpose

> 3. Simon says lets play charades

> 4. Do not look in other North Daniel puzzles for locations

Comment: Hey, that's me! :P

Comment: Have got pretty far in decoding this but I think there's a few typos - (i) The W at start of Simon's second line should be a 'U'; (ii) I think there is an error in your encoding for 'Scwjf jca fapnil?' (I think you forgot 'S', if you know what I mean...), and (iii) I just get gibberish (nothing like real words) for the next line after that (is that deliberate?). Wanted to double check these before committing any more time to it... Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi @Stiv, I'll check it over for errors - typical me!

Comment: I've fixed the errors hopefully

Comment: @Oliver Looking better now, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

<sub>*A partial answer - message decoded, but can't quite suss what to make of the output in order to reach the final answer...*</sub>

---

The way to decode this message is to use:

> a different **substitution cipher** for each line. Specifically, each line's cipher key is constructed by reducing the previous line's letters to only the first appearance of each letter in its plaintext. Match these up to A, B, C, etc. and when you run out of letters from the previous message, just list the remaining unused letters of the alphabet in their usual alphabetical order. For example...
>
>  The first line of the message is "ARE YOU THERE JUDE?" Reducing this to only the first appearance of each letter yields "AREYOUTH...J.D." Bunch these together and add on all the unused letters of the alphabet and your key for the next line of text is AREYOUTHJDBCFGIKLMNPQSVWXZ.

The message, therefore, translates as follows:

> **Simon: ARE YOU THERE JUDE?**
>
>  Jude: Xon j af. Vhomo amo vo foopjgt?
>  KEY: AREYOUTHJDBCFGIKLMNPQSVWXZ
>  Plaintext =  **Jude: YES I AM. WHERE ARE WE MEETING?**
>
>  Simon: Uagg gaol tplo lyx ikrcnl yka dc ba!
>  KEY: YESIAMWHRTNGBCDFJKLOPQUVXZ
>  Plaintext = **Simon: WELL LETS JUST SAY DRINKS ARE ON ME!**
>
>  Jude: Qawgf gas jycfg?
>  KEY: WELTSJUAYDRINKOMBCFGHPQVXZ
>  Plaintext = **Jude: WHATS THE FIRST?**
>
>  Simon: Vs ldwyst aisoo dwop vssc - awlpqnrjf ykqn lrsaso vwo swoy lswoy
>  KEY: WHATSEFIRBCDGJKLMNOPQUVXYZ
>  Plaintext = **Simon: WE PLAYED CHESS LAST WEEK – CAPTURING YOUR PIECES WAS EASY PEASY**
>
>  Jude: Qcwfb fca bapirl?
>  KEY: WEPLAYDCHSTKURINGOBFJMQVXZ
>  Plaintext = **Jude: WHATS THE SECOND?**
>
>  Simon: Kspqsmnic np ijq wffjvst ji nq'p jvi - jify ni psqp. Hfwab wit vonqs qnsp
>  KEY: WHATSECONDBFGIJKLMPQRUVXYZ
>  Plaintext = **Simon: PESTERING IS NOT ALLOWED ON IT’S OWN – ONLY IN SETS. BLACK AND WHITE TIES.**
>
>  Jude: O mytrhfjpyt
>  KEY: PESTRGINOALWDYBCKHFJMQUVXZ
>  Plaintext = **Jude: I UNDERSTAND**
>
>  Simon: We geep ip i opipan page - yjq otiff hjp ue fipe. Wiaopnjipo melqamed
>  KEY: IUNDERSTABCFGHJKLMOPQVWXYZ
>  Plaintext = **Simon: WE MEET AT A STATIC TIME – YOU SHALL NOT BE LATE. WAISTCOATS REQUIRED**
>
>  Jude: Dbiad
>  KEY: WEMTASICYOUHLNBRQDFGJKPVXZ
>  Plaintext = **Jude: ROGER**
>
>  Simon: Lm, ft's Sfkml!
>  KEY: ROGEABCDFHIJKLMNPQSTUVWXYZ
>  Plaintext = **Simon: NO, IT’S SIMON!**

So, now that the message is decoded, what do we do next? I'm not entirely sure, but worth noting that:

> we have not yet used the [geography](/questions/tagged/geography) tag - presumably what we have here are some clues to help us work out the location. As to what the 'first' and 'second' are, I am not yet entirely sure...

Next step needs some thought - or another eye to spot something I cannot!

Comment: Well done for getting this far! I've added a hint that may help